# Electrons in Bohr's atomic model

Tags: atomic-structure

Why electrons don't fall into the nucleus in bohr's atomic model?
Is there a reason or explanation or is just a consideration?

Comment: Is just a postulate, I think anyone can actually explain why.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54914/stability-of-bohr-orbits

Comment: @JorgeBonifaz That *was* a postulate - quantisation of energy. Now it's quite more than that and learning quantum mechanics gives some explanations.

Comment: So you mean it "was" in the past? Or only that was in some way the base of future advances in quantum mechanics?

Comment: @JorgeBonifaz I mean Bohr just postulated it, but future advances changed this situation.

Comment: The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It helps preventing  others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself, being answered many times in multiple ways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's a consideration that the electrons must describe circular orbits around the nucleus of the atom without radiating energy.

So this is because is a "postulate", since according to classical electrodynamics a charge with an accelerated movement must emit energy in the form of radiation.

To maintain the circular orbit, the force experienced by the electron (the Coulombian force due to the presence of the nucleus) must be equal to the centripetal force. So here it is:

Taken from [Chemistry Libretexts - 6.2 The Bohr Model](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Chemistry_(OpenSTAX)/06%3A_Electronic_Structure_and_Periodic_Properties_of_Elements/6.2%3A_The_Bohr_Model)

> $$k\frac{Ze^2}{r^2} = \frac{m_ev^2}{r}$$

Note that this model is only valid for hydrogen-like systems (only with 1 electron).

Comment: How does that relate with the "quantisation of energy"?

Comment: *since according to classical electrodynamics a charge with an accelerated movement must emit energy in the form of radiation.* - This is valid only for nonzero time derivative of acceleration vector. Linear constant acceleration does not lead to radiation, what is used in linear accelerators.